# Возможно ли подключиться программой на qt к Mysql базе на другом сервере?

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qt5

Возможно ли подключиться программой на qt к Mysql базе на другом сервере и изменять эту бд?

Comment: Вот [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/51650) посмотрите.

Comment: Да, можно... строка подключения к MySql выглядит примерно так `Database=DATABASENAME;Server=SERVERNAME;UID=USER;PWD=PASS;`

Answer (score 2):

IP-адрес сервера БД устанавливается с помощью метода

```
void QSqlDatabase::setHostName(const QString& hostName);
```

и совершенно не важно будет это локальный хост или удалённый.

Изучайте [документацию](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.6/qsqldatabase.html).

Простейший пример использования средств Qt для работы с БД:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
db.setHostName("your.remote.db.host");
db.setDatabaseName("your_db_name");
db.setUserName("your_username");
db.setPassword("your_password");

if (db.open())
{
    QSqlQuery query(db);
    if (query.exec("SELECT * FROM your_table;"))
    {
        while (query.next())
        {
            QSqlRecord row = query.record();
            for (int i = 0; i < row.count(); ++i)
            {
                qDebug() << QString("%1 = %2")
                            .arg(row.fieldName(i))
                            .arg(row.value(i).toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Точно так же можно выполнять запросы INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE. Главное чтобы сервер БД был доступен, а вашему пользователю хватало бы прав на изменение БД.

Comment: Не забудьте на сервере разрешить удалённое подключение.

Answer (score 0):

Да. Лично такое проворачивал, все работало.

QSqlDatabase вам понадобится в первую очередь.

Comment: Спс буду копать